# How to know if a variable is an integer when writing proof?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is the theorem:

> For all integers n, if n is odd then n^2 is odd.

This is the Proof:

---

Assume n is any odd integer. By definition of odd, $n = 2r + 1$, for some integer $r$.
We must show that the square of $n$ is odd. Then

$n = 2r + 1$

$= (2r+1) ^2$

$= 4r^2+4r+1$

$= 2(2r^2+2r)+1$

Let $2r^2+2r= k$. Notice that $k$ is integer because it’s the product of two integers. Hence $n^2 = 2(k) + 1$ in which $k$ is an integer. It follows by definition of odd, that $n^2$ is odd.

---

My problem is this step:

> Let $2r^2= k$. Notice that $k$ is integer because it’s the product of two integers.

I want to give a reason as to why K is an integer. I first thought that maybe because it's twice $r$, but then i thought since it's $r$ squared. So, I am confused to which one is valid.

Comment: Well, if $r$ is an integer, then so is $r^2$, and if $r^2$ is an integer, then so is $2r^2$.  More simply, any product of integers is an integer.

Comment: But beware, $(2r+1)^2\ne(4r)^2+1.$

Comment: The closure of integers under multiplication is a fact and not something you would normally need to justify. More on that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236939/proving-closure-of-mathbbz-under-multiplication

Comment: @lulu So $r^2$ is equivalent to $r * r$, And $2r^2$ is equivalent to $2(r*r)$.

Comment: @Anne Bauval  Oops! That's a mistake I did not notice.

Comment: @RTF i went to the other question, but I still don't understand. I would appreciate more clarification.

Comment: @Omar For example, the numbers 2 and 4 are integers and therefore  2*4=8 is also an integer. This is because when we multiply two (or more) integers we will always get an integer. Which means, we know that 2*4 is not 0.5 because 0.5 is not an integer. This is what we call "closure". It doesn't escape its set because it "closed" in it. Note, that not every set is closed under every operation. For instance, 2 and 5 are integers but 2/5 is not.

Comment: @emanresu Thanks, but when does it become necessary to include closure in a proof?

Comment: @Omar What do you mean?

Comment: @emanresu I am referring to this response from RTF: "The closure of integers under multiplication is a fact and not something you would normally need to justify".

Comment: @Omar What RTF means is that it's a known fact that the integers are closed under multiplication. And therefore when you have, as in your case, an integer $r$, it's obvious that $2r^2$ is an integer and you don't need to say "it's an integer because the integers are closed under multiplication".

Comment: @Omar When you create a new mathematical structure you will state the closure property. Once that is established it's not really mentioned again.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer multiplied by an integer, is an integer. This is because the set of integers is closed under multiplication. In your case, we have $2r^2$, because $r$ is an integer we get that $rr=r^2$ is an integer and therefore $2r^2=k$ is an integer. Regardless, your proof is not quite right. For example, you wrote $(2r+1)^2=(4r)^2+1$ which is not true.

Comment: "*because* the set of integers is *closed* under multiplication": actually, in this proof, we are not supposed to be aware of the existence of any other numbers than integers. Multiplication has no opportunity to escape this domain. It is *defined* as a map from pairs of integers to integers.

Comment: @AnneBauval We can talk about closure without referring to or implying a larger domain. Division is not closed on the integers since $1/0$ is not an integer. In most contexts we don't worry about whether $1/0$ is in some larger set, it just isn't anything.

Comment: @emanresu. $(2r+1)2=$$(4r)^2+1$ is a mistake I didn't notice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you for "We can talk about closure without referring to or implying a larger domain", I did not know that subtlety of english. As for division, it is off topic here but I think one says "the set of integers is not closed under division" (rather that the converse). What I meant about the *built in* "closure" of the set of integers under multiplication is much better detailed in the two answers to [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236939) provided by RTF.